# Using Group Symmetries to Translate a Solution Along Itself

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, lie-groups

Suppose that $G$ be the Lie symmetry group for a given set of differential equations (DEs) $\mathcal{D}$. Let $\mathcal{N}$ be the manifold representing $\mathcal{D}$ in jet space $\mathcal{P}$; i.e. $\mathcal{N} \subset \mathcal{P}$ is an embedding. Then, of course, $g.\mathcal{N} \subseteq \mathcal{N}$, $\forall\; g \in G$. Furthermore, any $g.[x, u]=[\bar{x}, \bar{u}]$ is the graph of a new solution $\bar{u}(\bar{x})$, as expected, where $x$ and $u$ stand for independent and dependent variables respectively.

The question is “whether the same G could be utilized to translate a solution $u(x)$ along itself”; i.e.:
$$
g.[x, u] = [ax-t, u(ax-t)],
$$
where $a,t \in \mathbb{R}$; s.t. $g \in G$ exists? By the way, it is , of course, valid for partial differential equations as well. My notation is just for the sake of clarity.

Comment: It looks to me like you just want the action of the symmetry group to be the fiber-preserving transformation $\mu_g([x,u]) = [\tilde{x}, \tilde{u}] = [ax - t, u]$, but whether or not this action exists will depend on the symmetry group of the system itself.

Comment: @Mobius, So sorry for the late reply. Yes, considering each solution as a fiber over a base space… I think I got your point! For instance, translating the solution u(x) along x-axis can not yield a solution so long as $ \partial_x$ is not admitted as an infinitesimal symmetry by the differential equation system. Then, it seems that symmetries may not always be used to translate a local region of the graph $(x, u(x))$, where  $x \in [x_0, x_1)$ to another local region where $x \in [x_k, x_{k+1})$?

Comment: That's correct. Take for example $u' = x$. It is easy to show that this equation does not admit translational symmetries and that a translation $x \mapsto x + 1$ will not preserve solutions.